# Inequivalent Model Categories

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

A Model Category is, informally, a category where a "reasonable" notion of homotopy
can be developed. I'm curious to know when two model categories are considered equivalent to each other. Thanks for any ideas, refs.

EDIT: My apologies ;  what I meant to ask was on different ( inequivalent) model categories defined on the same category.  Otherwise, like it
was pointed out, the answer to my original question can be found in many books; even in Wikipedia.

Comment: Zhen Lin's answer still applies. What do you want precisely? You probably know that two model category structures on a given category that have the same weak equivalences define the same homotopy category.

Comment: Well, I was wondering if there were some general results to this effect, of the type ( note I'm making this up just to illustrate, since I'm not too  knowledgeable on this area):" The categories for which there is more than one model categories are known to be small categories where colimits and pushouts commute, and where Yoneda's lemma fails. Or for someone knowledgeable enough to tell me that no such results are known or are not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The usual notion of equivalence for model categories is due to Quillen: given model categories $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, an adjunction
$$F \dashv G : \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{M}$$
is a **Quillen equivalence** if it is a Quillen adjunction (i.e. $F$ preserves cofibrations and trivial cofibrations, and $G$ preserves fibrations and trivial fibrations) such that the derived adjunction
$$\mathbf{L} F \dashv \mathbf{R} G : \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{N} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{M}$$
is an equivalence of categories. We say that two model categories are Quillen-equivalent if there is a zigzag of Quillen equivalences connecting them. This is all quite standard and can be found in any textbook on model categories.

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear. You're right that these concepts are found in any book, or even in the Wiki page. What I meant to ask was on different ( inequivallent) model categories defined on the same category. Let me edit the question.